# Horiontal lines on laptop screen when using Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04

Since a couple of months I've been getting these horizontal lines on my laptop display on Ubuntu 20.04.

[image]
[image]

My laptop is an Asus GL-502vm with a 6gb gtx1060

This issue doesn't happen on Windows 10 (I'm using a dual boot)
Also when I switch to the nouveau drivers everything works fine as well. (expect I need the Nvidia drivers for Cuda).
I also tried all available Nvidia drivers but this happens with all.

Sometimes when I login the screen stays black and I have to shutdown the laptop by holding the power button. This can happen multiple times in a row.

When I can login and I change some things in the display settings, like scaling (first to 125% it stops, then to 150% it starts again to go back to 100% and then it stops again), or in nvidia x server settings set underscan up a bit and click apply it also stops.

When I connect external monitors via hdmi or displayport the external monitors work fine, my internal monitor sometimes works sometimes not.

I called the Asus helpdesk and they told me the display cable was broken so I replaced this. That had no effect.

I also tried `Force Composition Pipeline` and `Force Full Composition Pipeline` in Nvidia x server settings. But that didn't work.

The kernel I'm using is:

```
5.8.0-45-generic
```

The output of xrandr is (the underscan is 2%):

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1916 x 1077, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1916x1077+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is the output of /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 460.39

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LGD"
    HorizSync       66.0 - 66.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Does anyone have any idea what is the cause of this and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
The lines start at the bottom and go up till about 1/3 of the screen there the flikker a bit and it starts from the bottom again.
During the flikkering if you listen really closely there's a sound like a blowfly coming from inside the laptop around the power button.

Comment: To confirm scaling at 100% works perfectly all the time?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No at startup it's 100% and the lines are there. It's just that after some rescaling back and forth the issue stops.

Comment: So a band-aid solution would be a startup script that ran early and forced scaling to 100% or worst case scenario forced to 125% and immediately back to 100%.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's not fixed the steps, sometimes it takes more tries then one before it works. It feels like it has to do with some memory or buffer thing which resets or empties when rescaling and then by chance works again.